# User feedback on multiple removal from items list

Tags: gui-design, copywriting

Think about the Photoshop History Panel…. When I want to remove an item in the middle of the list,  all of the subsequent items will be removed. I have a list with this behavior - I don’t know if this type of removal has a name! Do I need to give other information to the user, besides the UI? Photoshop pop up asks ‘Delete state X?’, referring to the selected item, and removes multiple (the pop up doesn’t alert me that I’m removing several items!).
I’ll not have a pop up. Do I need a sentence referring this behavior?
What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice to always ask for comfirmation when deleting something. Or give the user the option to undo (like Google does).

It's even better to prevent the user from being startled when reading "Are you sure you want to delete ALL these items?" "Wait what? All?"
You're UI should reflect the behavior. Like graying out all subsequent items when something is selected.